# MySQL code fails to display category name (WordPress database)

Tags: sql, mysql, database, wordpress, taxonomy

Why does this code fail to display the category name "Apples" using the current WordPress taxonomy system? The Category names are stored in the $wpdb->terms table (wp_terms).

```
<?php

$ra_category_id = 3; 
$ra_category = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id = '3'");
$ra_category_name = $ra_category->name;         

?>

<h3>Category: <?php echo $ra_category_name; ?></h3>
```

The table rows are

```
term_id     name              slug          term_group
1         Uncategorized     uncategorized   0
2         Blogroll          blogroll        0
3         Apples            apples          0
4         Bananas           bananas         0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ra_category is the following array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Apples"
  }
}
```

So what you want is:

```
$ra_category_name = $ra_category[0]->name;
```

When dealing with query results, always check the whole result with a `var_dump()`, it helps.

(note that you're also using `$ra_category_id` but then hardcoding the value "3" in your query)